# F/flutter ( 5152): [FATAL:flutter/shell/platform/android/surface_texture_external_texture.cc(56)] Check failed: state_ == AttachmentState::kAttached

Tags: flutter, google-maps, camera, geolocator

While working on a Flutter screen that allows toggling between the phone's rear camera and maps, both elements load correctly. However, when attempting to switch between them by tapping a button, an error occurs, leading to the app crashing. The error message is:

> F/flutter (5152):
> [FATAL:flutter/shell/platform/android/surface_texture_external_texture.cc(56)]
> Check failed: state_ == AttachmentState::kAttached. F/libc (5152):
> Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -1 (SI_QUEUE) in tid 5152
> (ample.switching), pid 5152 (ample.switching).

this is my current code of the screen:

```
class CameraScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CameraScreenState createState() => _CameraScreenState();
}

class _CameraScreenState extends State<CameraScreen> with WidgetsBindingObserver {
  late CameraController camera_controller;
  bool camera_preview_major = true;
  bool is_currposition_available = false;
  Position? currPosition;
  Map<MarkerId, Marker> markers = <MarkerId, Marker>{};
  Completer<GoogleMapController> _controller = Completer();
  late GoogleMapController mapsController;


  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    initCameraController();
    getCurrentPosition();
    requestLocationPermission();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // Dispose of the camera controller
    camera_controller.dispose();

    // Dispose of GoogleMapController if applicable
    // _controller.future.then((mapController) {
    //   mapController.dispose();
    // });

    super.dispose();
  }
  void toggleCameraPreview() {
    if (camera_preview_major) {
      // When switching to camera view, reinitialize the camera
      initCameraController();
    } else {
      // When switching away from camera view, dispose of the camera controller to free up resources
      camera_controller .dispose();
    }

    setState(() {
      camera_preview_major = !camera_preview_major;
    });
  }
  Future<void> requestLocationPermission() async {
    var status = await Permission.location.status;
    if (!status.isGranted) {
      await Permission.location.request();
    }
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: Stack(
              children: [
                // The camera preview is shown in full screen by default
                camera_preview_major ? getCameraPreview(camera_controller, size) : getMaps(),
                Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                  children: [
                    InkWell(
                      onTap: () {
                        setState(() {
                          camera_preview_major = !camera_preview_major; // Toggle the view
                        });
                      },
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        child: Row(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                          children: [
                            Container(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10, vertical: 5),
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                boxShadow: [
                                  BoxShadow(color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.14), blurRadius: 4, spreadRadius: 1),
                                ],
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100),
                              ),
                              child: Row(
                                children: [
                                  Icon(
                                    camera_preview_major ? Icons.location_on : Icons.camera_alt_rounded,
                                    color: Colors.blueAccent,
                                    size: 20,
                                  ),
                                  SizedBox(width: 5),
                                  Text(camera_preview_major ? "Maps View" : "Camera View"),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                            Expanded(child: Container()),
                            Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                              child: Container(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 2, vertical: 2),
                                width: size.width / 3,
                                height: size.width / 3,
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  boxShadow: [
                                    BoxShadow(color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.14), blurRadius: 4,        spreadRadius: 1),
                                  ],
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4),
                                ),
                                // The maps are shown in the small box by default
                                child: camera_preview_major ? getMaps() : getCameraPreview(camera_controller, size),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  getCameraPreview(CameraController controller, Size size) {
    if (!controller.value.isInitialized&&camera_controller != null) {
      return const SizedBox(
          height: 2,
          width: 2,
          child: LinearProgressIndicator(
            color: Colors.grey,
          ));
    }
    return SizedBox(width: size.width, child: CameraPreview(controller));
  }
  initCameraController() {
    camera_controller = CameraController(
        config.cameras[0], ResolutionPreset.low,
        enableAudio: false);
    camera_controller.initialize().then((_) {
      if (!mounted) {
        return;
      }
      setState(() {});
    }).catchError((Object e) {
      if (e is CameraException) {
        switch (e.code) {
          case 'CameraAccessDenied':
            break;
          default:
            print('Handle other errors.');
            break;
        }
      }
    });
    camera_controller.addListener(() async {
      // camera_controller.value.isRecordingPaused


    });
  }
  getMaps() {
    return is_currposition_available
        ? GoogleMap(
      zoomControlsEnabled: false,
      myLocationEnabled: true,
      myLocationButtonEnabled: true,
      compassEnabled: true,
      initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
        target: LatLng(currPosition?.latitude ?? 0.0,
            currPosition?.longitude ?? 0.0),
        zoom: config.mapsInitialZoom,
      ),
      markers: Set<Marker>.of(markers.values),
      onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
        if (!_controller.isCompleted) {
          _controller.complete(controller);
          mapsController = controller;
        }
      },
    )
        : Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
  }
  getCurrentPosition() {
    Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.best)
        .then((pos) {
      setState(() {
        currPosition = pos;
        is_currposition_available = true;
      });
    }).catchError((e) {
      print("Error getting location: $e");
      // Handle the error by showing an alert dialog or a snackbar
      // or by setting a flag to show a message in the UI
    });
  }



}
```

Comment: Could you please check if your issue is related to [this](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/138947)?

Answer (score 1):

I can reproduce this issue on stable 3.16.9 but it seems to be fixed on the 3.19.0

Comment: I got the same crash using flutter webview package when clicking on youtube full screen button. 3.19 well fix that, ty mate :)